# Jaxb API Listener

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, jaxb2

I have created Jaxb Class that contains following listener method but only unmarshall method is working :

```
void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        System.out.println("afterUnmarshal  1");
    }

    void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller, Object parent) {
        System.out.println("beforeMarshal  2");
    }

    void beforeUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        System.out.println("beforeUnmarshal  3");
    }

    void afterMarshal(Marshaller marshaller, Object parent) {
        System.out.println("afterMarshal  4");
    }
```

**OutPut :**

```
beforeUnmarshal  3
afterUnmarshal  1
```

No marshall method is called on execution of marshalling code .

---

**Updated Question : 
Problem :** beforeMarshal  Customer called two times .
**OutPut :**

```
afterUnmarshal  Address
afterUnmarshal  Customer
beforeMarshal  Customer
beforeMarshal  Customer
beforeMarshal  Address
```

**Program :**

```
 public class Demo {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class,ObjectFactory.class);

            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            File xml = new File("src/testRJE/input.xml");
            Customer customer = (Customer) u.unmarshal(xml);

            Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
            m.marshal(customer, xml);
        }

    }


    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Customer {

      @XmlElementRef(name = "billing-address")
      @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AddressAdapter.class)
      private Address address;

        public Address getAddress() {
            return address;
        }


        void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {//XML to Object
        System.out.println("afterUnmarshal  Customer");
    }

    void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller ) {
        System.out.println("beforeMarshal  Customer");
    }

    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Address {

        public Address() {
        }


        private String street;

        private String city;

      void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        System.out.println("afterUnmarshal  Address");
    }

    void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller ) {
        System.out.println("beforeMarshal  Address");
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marshal event methods don't have an `Object` parameter like the unmarshal methods do.  When your remove them from your method signatures everything should work as expected.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have extended the the class [Unmarshaller#Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html) which has only the methods `afterUnmarshal`  and `beforeUnmarshal` which explains why only those two are called.

In order to Listen to marshaling events you need to have another Listener class extending [Marshaller#Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.Listener.html) which in its turn has the methods you need and which you have to override.

Also please annotate methods you override with the annotation `@Override`. Having done that in your class you should have got errors saying that the class `Unmarshaller#Listener` does not have any methods `beforeMarshal` or `afterMarshal`.